# is it possible write watchtower logs in single file in aws

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs, docker-watchtower

I have developed one small application. For logs , i'm using watchtower in aws. logs are working fine.Logs are inserted in cloudwatch by file wise [logs in aws](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uG8Rm.png) but i wants all logs to be registered in a single file only (for example api.views ) .is this possible? if yes, how?

Answer (score 1):

solved this problem... i have written logs function in one file.. calling that function wherever i want to write logs.... so all logs are saving with same file name